# Video ppt sync on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, mobile, video-streaming, html5-video, mobile-browser

I have been stuck on this issue for a month now and haven't found any solution.

I am developing a web page where there is a LIVE video stream of a presenter and an image for the ppt slides. Now, when the presenter changes the slide, our web page should change the slide image correspondingly.
I am using jQuery to get the slide images but there is always a delay of +1 to +10 seconds(or more) as HTTP is unreliable on 3g, 4g data and buffering is also an issue for ppt sync. I want to get rid of this delay and make it feel like the slides are synced in real time.

I am using JWplayer with HTTP streaming protocol. Any other player that works on mobile devices for video ppt sync is welcomed.

RTMP does not work on mobile devices and it cannot be used. Also, metadata cannot be read by mobile browsers and hence we cannot get the cue point from metadata.

Please share your solutions as this would help me finish this project.

Comment: No replies yet. Has nobody been working on issues like this!!

Comment: How are you triggering the fact an update to the slides has happened/is required? Is a flag simply set on the "presenter" side which is currently polled for by each client (using setTimeout/AJAX)? I'd suggest you look at WebRTC or similar to set up a "realtime" communications channel between presenter (host) and clients (peers) rather than polling via HTTP.

Comment: Yes there is a flag set which indicates a slide change on the presenter side and setTimeout/AJAX is used to trigger this slide change. WebRTC would take up a lot of bandwidth and won't have much video play back quality controls.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not necessary to use video to cope with this task. Actually, you can use HTML5 and set up programmed control of playback. This is how iSpring Platform works. Before a presentation starts, upload it to a server where it will be converted into HTML5 or Flash. When a presenter switches slides on his end, the server sends out the information about the necessary slide to all the participants. They load the presentation, which obeys commands from the central server and automatically switches to the necessary slide.

This solution is perhaps even better than recording video, as it’s more close-knit: HTML5 looks better, texts are clearer, weighs less, and can be viewed on mobile devices. Here’s a link if you’re interested: http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring-platform

Comment: I have been stuck on this for months now and my client is going crazy and I am on the verge of getting lost. Please somebody help me with this.

How do we do video ppt sync for live stream on mobile browsers?